# fragment disappear when came back from tab 3

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, ondestroy

I have an Activity with a ViewPager containing Fragments.
the first fragment(book) create a nested fragment(singlebook) when click a button on it.
Problem is that the first fragment and its component are gone when i came back from fragment3. I think it is related onSaveState or onDestroy.

I've tried Override onDestroy and used childFragmentManager on parent fragment(book) but it doesn't add to back stack.

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
MyPagerAdapter adapter;
public FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl_tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_12);

    Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[3];
    fragments[0] = new Book();
    fragments[1] = new Search();
    fragments[2] = new Study();
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, fragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Fragment[] fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragments[0];
            case 1:
                return fragments[1];
            case 2:
                return fragments[2];
            default:
                return fragments[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "단어장";
            case 1:
                return "단어 검색";
            case 2:
                return "내 정보";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Book.java :**

```
public class Book extends Fragment {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Button btn;
private EditText editText;

public Book() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_toQuiz);
    editText =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fl_BookContainer,new singleBook(),"TAG")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use of parent FragmentManager to add the new fragment?

Comment: have you tried viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); where 3 is your number of pages

Comment: It works! thank you very much!

Comment: @MrazJason if you found this comment is helpful then mark as an upvote. it will help others also

Comment: how to upvote? I'm very new this site. I really appreciate again. where can i find upvote mark?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_12);


adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, fragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

To

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_12);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default FragmentStatePagerAdapter can only create two fragments and when you go to the third fragment it will remove the first one. so that the solution is you need to call **setOffscreenPageLimit** method save all fragments which added into pager adapter when set adapter into view pager.

```
Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[3];
fragments[0] = new Book();
fragments[1] = new Search();
fragments[2] = new Study();
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, fragments);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragments.size());
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```